# Creating a ball of roughly equidistant points

Tags: matlab, points

I need to create a sphere which has more or less equidistant points for my simulation.
I've looked at some codes, but they all give just a surface of a sphere, whilst I need the ball to be filled with equidistant points starting at the center.

Before, I created a cube then cut out the radius, but this gives me flat edges whilst I need it to be more circular so it is actually resembling a ball.

How can I create an equidistant grid in a ball?

Comment: I have found an article describing exactly what you want, with a [spiral grid](https://agupubs.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/epdf/10.1029/2007GC001581). Unfortunately, no code is available.

Comment: Note: a *sphere* is defined as the surface of a *ball*. These are the two mathematical terms for the 3D geometric shapes. You want to create a *ball*, not a *sphere*. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ball_(mathematics)

Answer (score 4):

I use the following to create a grid of approximately equidistant points on a spherical shell. It is based on the choice of an appropriate `delta_theta`, i.e. (co-)latitudinal bin width. The longitudinal, `phi`, width is then chosen as `delta_theta./sind(theta_c)`, where `theta_c` is the central latitude of the bin. In words: bins get wider (smaller) in longitude when moving away from (towards) the equator.

*Note: I use colatitudes and degrees, i.e. `theta = [0 180)` and `phi = [0 360)`. Its final output are two variables: `theta` and `phi`. They are of equal length and `(theta(i),phi(i))` are centre points of the bins.*

```
delta_theta = 1;  % latitudinal bin width
theta_c = 0:delta_theta:89;  % Set up bin centres
theta_c = [-fliplr(theta_c) theta_c].'+90;  % Centre the centres on the equator
delta_phi = delta_theta./sind(theta_c);  % Grab longitudinal bin width per latitudinal bin
bins_per_theta = round(360./delta_phi);  % Ensure an integer number of bins

theta = zeros(sum(bins_per_theta),1);
phi = theta;
kk=1;

for ii=1:numel(theta_c)  % We need a loop here to deal with the changing number of bins
    phi_c =  linspace(0,360,bins_per_theta(ii));
    kk_add = numel(phi_c);
    theta(kk:kk+kk_add-1) = theta_c(ii);
    phi(kk:kk+kk_add-1) = phi_c;
    kk = kk+kk_add;
end
```

A simple loop over this code to decrease `delta_theta` appropriately based on radius would fill this up to a full ball. I'd say `delta_theta = 1/r`, with an appropriate constant, would do to decrease the latitudinal bin width with increasing radius. Perhaps you'd need an offset in `theta_c` and `phi_c` as well, to prevent pure radial lines.

Comment: Collecting many spheres of increasing size might not lead to a nicely sampled volume, sampling is hard... Still, this seems like a good solution.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I don't understand how to plot this sphere sorry.

Comment: @kbez how do you mean "Do not know how to plot"? This code is for a spherical surface, as mentioned, so you provide a routine like `plot3` with some fixed radius, and then then given colatitude and longitude (might have to convert them to radians). For a ball, the mentioned extension at the end of the post should do; wrap this entire code in a loop over radius `r` and change `delta_theta` according to some appropriate criterion. Then again, you'll have three arrays: `r, theta, phi`, which are spherical coordinates and can be plotted as such.

Answer (score 2):

For sampling a volume, the most straight-forward solution is always a regular grid. Randomly selecting points leads to a less efficient sampling (you need more points to get the same representation, this is a result from Stereology).

But the cubic grid is not the only regular grid we can use to sample a volume! Atoms in crystals can arrange in various different grids, most suitably for us are the cubic grid, the face-centered cubic grid (FCC), and the body-centered cubic grid (BCC) -- other grids are less isotropic. Many research papers have been published on the use of these grids to sample volumetric images, it turns out that the FCC and BCC grids are significantly more efficient than the cubic grid when sampling a volume. That means, that fewer samples are needed to represent the volume with the same error. Note that, for example, fruit vendors will stack oranges and apples using either the FCC or the BCC grid, because they lead to the densest possible sphere packing.

Whether to use FCC or BCC grid sampling, or a method like [Adriaan's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63897664/7328782) depends on what is most important: a good sampling of the volume itself, or a good sampling of the edges of the volume.

[image: samples and voxel shape in the cubic, FCC and BCC grids (image copied from somewhere on the web)]

The simple cubic grid is represented by the following matrix:

```
 1  0  0
 0  1  0
 0  0  1
```

The FCC grid is represented by the following matrix:

```
 1  1  0
 1  0  1
 0  1  1
```

The BCC grid is represented by the following matrix:

```
 1  1 -1
 1 -1  1
-1  1  1
```

The rows of these matrices represent the unit vectors of the grid. The coordinates for any grid point can be obtained by multiplying the matrix by the index vector:

```
M * [i;j;k]
```

To find the set of points in the ball, we can do:

```matlab
d = 0.3; % grid spacing
r = 2.3; % ball size
M = [1  1  0
     1  0  1
     0  1  1]; % FCC grid
p = -2*r/d : 2*r/d; % take a larger area around the ball, so we're sure to sample the whole thing
[i, j, k] = ndgrid(p, p, p);
p = [i(:).'; j(:).'; k(:).'];
p = (d * M) * p;
I = sqrt(sum(p.^2, 1)) < r; % can use `vecnorm` in newer MATLAB releases
p = p(:, I);
scatter3(p(1,:), p(2,:), p(3,:))
axis equal
```

Comment: Hi thank you @Cris for the reply. The results are very nice, the only problem is that it still gives these flat edges. I'm using it for a collision so I need somewhat rounded edges to apply the force more realistically